# onReceive called when it shouldn't

Tags: android, android-widget, android-wifi

some seconds ago I was debugging my widget and I've found that the `onReceive` method is called even if my widget isn't on the home screen (it listens for `WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` ). Even if the process of my widget isn't running, it will be started and the method called.
The code in the manifest is the following:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">

    <receiver android:name="WiFiWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" 
                   android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
    </receiver>

</application>
```

The method `onReceive` simply calls another method `toggleState` ( to change the wifi state ) and then updates the widget image ( from off to on image or viceversa ).

Obviously the call of the two methods toggleState and updateWidget ( and so the complete onReceive ) are useless if the widget isn't actually active on the home screen..

So, I want my `onReceive` called only if my widget is effectively placed on home screen..there's a way to do this? :)

thanks in advance for the answers

Comment: Can you edit your question to be a bit more specific about how you are setting up this `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: You are right, sorry :)..Code added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't your broadcast receiver be called? That's the point of a broadcast receiver is to be called when your process/activity isn't running.

If you only want it called at certain times, you have to register it in code in your widget, and unregister it when you don't want to receive broadcasts.

Comment: The point is, if my widget isn't placed on the home screen, why the system must call the onReceive? :) It's useless

Comment: How is the system supposed to know that? All it knows is there's a broadcast receiver registered to receive broadcasts on WIFI_STATE_CHANGED. So it delivers it.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for a method ( if exists ) to let the system know that my widget isn't on the home screen and the call to the onReceive is useless :P

Comment: You have to declare and register your receiver inside your widget code, not in the xml.